# Home and End key stop working with M-[ f is undefined

Tags: key-bindings

I am running a session of emacs (GNU Emacs 24.5.1) in a qt konsole (Konsole: 2.14.2, KDE: 4.14.21, Qt: 4.8.7) with the command emacs -nw on a local machine. At the start of my session, the Home and End keys work just fine. However, after a while, the Home and End keys stop working and the message "M-[ f is undefined" appears in the minibuffer.

Closing emacs and opening it again with emacs -nw solves the problem. The phenomen happens sometimes after copying data into the editor-buffer by the konsole copy and paste function.

The related question at [Home and End keys stop working correctly](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26103/home-and-end-keys-stop-working-correctly) describes a similar situation, but as restarting emacs solves the problem a terminal issue does not step forward as probable cause.

What does the switch in behaviour of emacs reacting to home and end keys cause ?

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably removing the key binding for `M-[`, or replacing it with something else. Perhaps a package you are loading is doing it for you. Note that inside of a terminal, many common keys produce an escape sequence that starts with `M-[`.